# modifying select box option text in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html-select

Given the following HTML:

```
<select id="addSelection">

<option value="Original Value">Original Value</option>

</select>
```

I would like to change the text value of the option tag when I click on a button.

Assuming that the button click can be done correctly...how can I change the text of the option tag using jQuery?

So, for example...I would like the option tag changed to this:

```
<option value="New Value">New Value</option>
```

I've tried using variations of the `.val()` function but have not found a solution.

Thank you to all who reply!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Treat the option like any other piece of HTML. `$option.attr('value')` will give you the content of the `value` attribute and `$option.text()` or `$option.html()` will give you the content between the opening and closing tags.

```
$('#mybutton').click(function(){
    var $option = $('#addSelect option:content("Original Value")');
    $option.attr('value', 'New Value');
    $option.text('New Value');
});
```

Comment: This is very helpful; thanks.  A couple questions however.  1) Is `.text()` or `.html()` the preferred way of doing this?  2) Is `option.attr('value', 'New Value')` or [as genesis wrote below] `option.val('NewValue')` the preferred way of doing this?

Comment: It's mostly stylistic as far as this example is concerned. There's no functional difference between `option.val()` and `option.attr('value')`, but since calling `.val()` on the select actually affects which option is selected rather than the actual value of the option, I went with `attr('value')` to be more explicit. `.text()` and `.html()` are interchangeable depending on whether you're adding HTML in the contents or not. Since there's no HTML, I went with `.text()`, but `.html()` will still work even if there's no HTML.

Answer (score 10):

The following simplified solution ...

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.5.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" >
    function domread() {
        $('#btn').click(function(){
            $('#originalValue').attr('value', 'New Value').html('New Value');
        });
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="domread()">
<select id="addSelection">
  <option id="originalValue" value="Original Value">Original Value</option>
  <option value="Two Value">Value two</option>
  <option value="Three Value">Value three</option>
</select>
<br/>
<input id="btn" type="button" value="Changes"></input>
</body>
</hmtl>
```

Answer (score 6):

Considering the following file. html:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.5.2.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<select id="addSelection">
  <option value="Original Value">Original Value</option>
  <option value="Original Value">Value two</option>
</select>
<br/>
<input id="btn" type="button" value="Changes"></input>
</body>
</hmtl>
```

The following javascript code with jquery to solve the problem:

```
$('#btn').click(function(){
    var $option = $('#addSelection option:contains("Original Value")');
    $option.attr('value', 'New Value');
    $option.html('New Value');
});
```

Comment: The OP accepted my answer, so it's a moot point. But seriously? Did you really just copy my answer and change '#mybutton' to '#btn' and '$option.text' to '$option.html'. Other than that, it's a complete copy-paste job, and I find it hard to believe that you just happened to do that on your own from scratch by accident.

Comment: I apologize. It was not my intention to generate a new answer, the only correct answer is that chrisdpratt with errors (bugged).
My intention was to leave an answer that you could use without spending time fixing something that was voted correctly, but that did not work in full. The code changes were implemented to test for and correct. Took the opportunity to test alternatives such as. Html () instead of. Text () proposed by Genesis-φ.
I am a new user and had no intention of stealing the soluçãodo chrisdpratt, just fix it and leave it testable (hence the code. html).

Answer (score 2):

You were on the right way with `.val()`

```
var option = $("#addSelection option");
option.val('New Value');
option.html('New Value');
```

Comment: Perfect.  I didn't have the third line with the .html...that's the part I was missing.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
$("option[value='New Value']").html("Another value");
```

Answer (score 0):

To change the selection option:

```
$("#addSelection").find(":selected").text("foo");

$("#addSelection").find(":selected").attr("value", "foo");

$("#addSelection").find(":selected").html("foo");
```

To change a particular option (not necessarily the selected option):

```
$("#addSelection option[value='Original Value']").text("foo");

$("#addSelection option[value='Original Value']").html("foo");
```

Comment: That will simply set the currently selected option, not the value attribute of the option.

Answer (score 0):

Use this to just update selected text

```
$('#dropdown option:selected').text('whatever');
```

Use this to update select value

```
$('#dropdown option:selected').val('whatever');
```